# Skinnable wiki

Tags: wiki, themes, skin

Are there any wikis that can be skinned with html/css/images? We've gone through the process of getting custom html for a blog (wordpress) and for our app and would like to be able to use those designs with a wiki.

Comment: A better question would be, are there any wikis that CANNOT be skinned?

Comment: - Skins for MediaWiki: https://github.com/mwskin - Skins for DokuWiki: https://github.com/dwskin

Answer (score 2):

[Mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Skinning) is fairly flexible to skin, with a bit of effort. A guy called [Paul Gu](http://paulgu.com/wiki/Mediawiki_Skins) in Canada has made a few for example. Some other MediaWiki skins and galleries:

- [paulgu.com/wiki/Mediawiki_Skins](http://paulgu.com/wiki/Mediawiki_Skins)
- [mediawiki2u.com](http://mediawiki2u.com)
- [mediawiki.org/wiki/Gallery_of_user_styles](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gallery_of_user_styles)

Comment: It's not really much effort.  It uses standard CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: I guess it depends how much the theme needs to be changed. Obviously a skin such as the one developed for http://www.aboutus.org (using MediaWiki) can take a bit of effort. TO have complete control and flexibility with any system takes effort I guess.

Answer (score 1):

[Mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/), the Wiki software used by Wikipedia, is skinnable.

Answer (score 1):

TWiki has many skins that are CSS based:

http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Plugins/SkinPackage

Answer (score 0):

Try embedding a [dooWiki](http://doowikis.com) into one of the pages that you want skinned.  It's just SaaS for HTML publishing and so it takes on whatever CSS you give it.